# how to split my arraylist when i write it on a file

Tags: java

Below you see a part of my program that I write my `arraylist` in a file but I have a problem that I need to split the text with `\t` when I write it on the file how do I fix that?

```
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    int counter = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < counter+1; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            output.write("ProductID " + "ProductName    " + "SupplierID " + "CategoryID " + "Unit   " + "Price  " + "Amount" + System.lineSeparator());
        } else {
            output.write(list.get(i-1).toString() + "\t" + antalVaror.get(i-1) + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    output.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How I want it to be:
[image: Desired output]

What I actually get from the code above:

[image: What I actually get]

Comment: your toString() method should add `\t` between fields

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov thx works very well now realy didint think of that easy solution